# Блокировка всех потоков другим потоком python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

```
def func1():
    # some action
    for c in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('func1', c)
    print('end func1')

def func2():
    # some other action
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('func2', i)
    print('end func2')

def main():
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
    thread1.start()
    # time.sleep(10)
    thread2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Требуется приостановить поток thread1 на время выполнения thread2, затем возобновить его в прежнем состоянии. Потоков типа thread1 несколько, нужно приостанавливать их все.

Пробовал threading.Lock(), но не совсем понял принцип действия данного метода.

Как я могу это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну, в таком примитивном случае достаточно просто завести глобальную переменную типа `приостановить_потоки = False` и внутри потоков проверять её состояние `while приостановить_потоки: time.sleep(5)`. Но что-то я подозреваю, что реальный код на самом деле более сложный

Comment: @andreymal идея хорошая, однако в таком случае остановка будет происходить в определённом месте первой функции, хотя по моей задумке пауза должна осуществляться в произвольной части функции.

Comment: В произвольной части останавливать нельзя, иначе python-интерпретатор тоже окажется в "произвольном" состоянии и всё сломается к чертям

Comment: Вы ещё и `join`-ы забыли. Без них у вас скрипт закончится досрочно, не дожидаясь окончания работы потоков.

Comment: Заменил threading на multiprocessing и добавил terminate в нужном месте. Не совсем то, что планировалось, но работает исправно и логику не рушит.